# Can I Uninstall Breeze in Kubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, themes, uninstall

I want to unistall the Breeze and Kubuntu themes. I don't like them and I don't use them. But since they came as standard with the Kubuntu 20.04.2 I'm running I wonder if this is possible without wrecking my system. I don't use any of their parts (styles, clock and things like that) either. Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to remove something which is basic to your system and *stays out of the way if you don't want it*. You risk to break the basic structure of desktop appearance too. (The only reason I don't down-vote is your new contributor status. By the way I only use breeze dark, have tried the best of customization including Kvantum and in the end came back to breeze-dark!). Anyway, see my next comment.

Comment: 'Themes'  in Plasma are structured at multiple levels (no less then four) and present in multiple locations on the system. Take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1392795/925128) answer. As you speak of Breeze AND Kubuntu, I guess you are referring to the "global themes", which are in `/usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel`. But modifying such files is not advisable.

Comment: @ Cipricus  Thank you for your comments and time. I just let them be were they are.